# Using cursor within UDF, returns a column which has name of different table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, cursor, user-defined-functions

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetStockDeatils]()
RETURNS @Results TABLE
(
PurchaseData nvarchar(50) NOT NULL 

)
AS
    BEGIN


    Declare @tableName varchar(25)
    Declare @PKKey numeric(18,0)

    DECLARE StockCursor CURSOR FOR Select tableName ,PKKey from INVM 
    OPEN StockCursor
    FETCH StockCursor INTO @tableName ,@PKKey 
       Begin

         Insert @Results Select PurchaseData from @tableName.PKKey =@PKKey 

       END      
    FETCH StockCursor INTO @tableName ,@PKKey 
    close StockCursor
    DEALLOCATE StockCursor


        Return  

    END
```

I have already written this but it does not working properly. `@tableName` contains the name of the table. Please help me if possible.

Comment: This is a very non-relational data design.  This is going to cause you numerous problems like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need an [**dynamic SQL commands**](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/), but you cannot use dynamic SQL from a function. For that you have to create stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStockDeatils]
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @tableName varchar(25),
        @PKKey numeric(18,0),
        @dsql nvarchar(max) = N''

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#Results
CREATE TABLE dbo.#Results(PurchaseData nvarchar(50) NOT NULL)

DECLARE StockCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT tableName ,PKKey 
FROM INVM 
OPEN StockCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM StockCursor INTO @tableName, @PKKey
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
  SET @dsql = 'Insert dbo.#Results Select PurchaseData from ' + @tableName + ' WHERE PKKey = ' + CAST(@PKKey AS varchar(10))
  EXEC sp_executesql @dsql  
  FETCH NEXT FROM StockCursor INTO @tableName, @PKKey 
END
CLOSE StockCursor
DEALLOCATE StockCursor

SELECT *
FROM dbo.#Results
END

EXEC [dbo].[GetStockDeatils]
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3271c/1)

Procedure creating view

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStockDeatils]
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @dsql nvarchar(max) = N''
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.v_Results') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW dbo.v_Results
SELECT @dsql += 
  'UNION ALL SELECT PurchaseData FROM ' + tableName + 
  ' WHERE PKKey = ' + CAST(PKKey AS varchar(10))                
FROM dbo.INVM
SET @dsql = N'CREATE VIEW dbo.v_Results AS ' + STUFF(@dsql, 1, 10, '')
EXEC sp_executesql @dsql
END

EXEC [dbo].[GetStockDeatils]

SELECT *
FROM dbo.v_Results
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot for you reply. i tried this method. its working fine but when i try to execute  SELECT * FROM dbo.#Results statement, it is showing me "Invalid object name '#Results'". I guess it is not creating a table. but if it is not creating a table then how come the insert statement is working properly. do u have any solution?

Comment: Is there any way to create a view using this method instead of creating a table. Actually i want to combine data present in my invm table and some data which comes from different tables, whose names are present in a column in invm table.

Comment: SELECT statement contain in the body of stored procedure. To execute procedure need EXEC command. I update my answer

Comment: Thank u so much Sir. i Really appreciate your help. Thanks alot. i have another question. can i create view instead of creating table. for performance sake? is it possible?

Comment: create view without stored procedure?

Comment: no with stored procedure only. same procedure but instead of creating a table i was thinking of creating a view. i dont know whether it is feasible or not.